# Invoking a java method from Azure Data factory pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Im working on a project where i need to ingest `EBCDIC` files to Azure  blob storage  and transform it using Azure Paas Services.

High Level design is as follows:

Ingest file to Azure using AZcopy Do the transformation using ADF.

Before doing transformation i need to convert  `EBCDIC` file to `Ascii` and the best solution is using `JRecord` which is written in java.

I created a custom solution to convert my files  using `JRecord` and deployed it as an app in Azure.

Can some one help how can I invoke this app from an activity in Azure Data Factory pipeline?

Comment: How did you deployed it as an app?

Comment: We refereed the documentation on azure java and deployed the jar from eclipse but we are not successful in the deployment

Comment: @Sreejith Hi,Sreejith.Any progress about your java app deployment? Please post more details about your deployment details to let me help you.

Comment: We were unsuccessful abd finally what we did is developed a .net assembly ti convert ebvidic to ascii and custom .net activity to integrate it to data pipeline